# LeetCode: Can't figure out binary search issue

Tags: java, binary-search

I am trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/successful-pairs-of-spells-and-potions/editorial/) problem and below is my code. My approach is to sort the potions and find the index where product of `spell*potion` becomes successful, since the array is sorted so rest of the elements from that index will satisfy the success condition and I can find out the total successful combinations. My code does not pass all the test cases however when I checked one of the solutions it uses similar approach and it passes all test cases. I am unable to figure out why my code fails.

**My Code:**

```
class Solution {
    static int binarySearch(int[] potions, long success, long spell){
        int start = 0, end = potions.length - 1, mid = 0;
        while(start <= end){
            mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
            long product = (long)potions[mid] * spell;
            if(product == success)
                return mid;
            else if(product < success)
                start = mid + 1;
            else
                end = mid - 1;
        }
        return start;
    }
    
    public static int[] successfulPairs(int[] spells, int[] potions, long success) {
        Arrays.sort(potions);
        for(int i = 0; i < spells.length; i++){
            int index = binarySearch(potions, success, (long)spells[i]);
            if(index == potions.length)
                spells[i] = 0;
            else
                spells[i] = potions.length - index;
        }
        return spells;
    }
}
```

It fails the below test case:

```
spells=[40,11,24,28,40,22,26,38,28,10,31,16,10,37,13,21,9,22,21,18,34,2,40,40,6,16,9,14,14,15,37,15,32,4,27,20,24,12,26,39,32,39,20,19,22,33,2,22,9,18,12,5]
potions=[31,40,29,19,27,16,25,8,33,25,36,21,7,27,40,24,18,26,32,25,22,21,38,22,37,34,15,36,21,22,37,14,31,20,36,27,28,32,21,26,33,37,27,39,19,36,20,23,25,39,40]
success=600
expected=[48,0,32,37,48,22,33,47,37,0,43,6,0,46,0,21,0,22,21,14,46,0,48,48,0,6,0,0,0,3,46,3,45,0,34,20,32,0,33,47,45,47,20,18,22,45,0,22,0,14,0,0]
```

Below code is one of the accepted solutions

```
class Solution {
     public int[] successfulPairs(int[] spells, int[] potions, long success) {
        int n = spells.length;
        int m = potions.length;
        int[] pairs = new int[n];
        Arrays.sort(potions);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int spell = spells[i];
            int left = 0;
            int right = m - 1;
            while (left <= right) {
                int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
                long product = (long) spell * potions[mid];
                if (product >= success) {
                    right = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    left = mid + 1;
                }
            }
            pairs[i] = m - left;
        }
        return pairs;
    }
}
```

It too is based on the same idea as my approach but my code fails. I believe I am missing some nuances of Binary Search but I am unable to figure out exactly what as I am still learning. Also if I change the condition in the above code as

```
if (product <= success) 
{
    left = mid + 1;
} 
else{
    right = mid - 1; 
}
```

it starts failing some of the test cases. Does it matter what condition I put first in my code? Whether I should write `<=` first or `>=` should not affect the output right?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is problematic:

```
if(product == success)
    return mid;
```

If you observe closely, you are returning mid simply whereas you should be returning the smallest index which satisfies the condition. This would fail in cases like below:

I/P: spells: [3,4,1], success: 6, potions: [1 2 3 3 3 4 5]
It will find mid which will be index 3 and return it where it should be returning index 2

The below piece of code ensures this scenario:

```
if (product >= success) {
    right = mid - 1;
```

Even if the product == success, it will still try and find leftmost element which still satisfies this condition and won't simply return mid as in your code.